# Extract all words from text field in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search

I have a table that contains text fields. In those fields I store text. There are around 20 to 50 sentences in each field depending on the row.  I am making an auto-complete HTML object with HTML and PHP, and I would like to start typing the beginning of a word and that the database return sentences containing those words (Like Microsoft office 2007/2010 navigation pane).

I need mysql to return those words or sentences as a separate result, so i can manipulate them further.

Example:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| id    | title |content                                            |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1 |  test 1    |  PHP is a very nice language and has nice features.
2 |  test 2    |  Spain is a nice country to visit and has nice language.
3 |  test 3    |  Perl isn\'t as nice a language as PHP.
```

I need mysql query to return following as different result:

```
1,"nice language"
1,"nice features"
2,"nice country"
2,"nice langugage"
3,"nicea a language"
```

Here is my sql query:

```
SELECT id, SUBSTR(content,POSITION('nice' IN content),50)
    FROM entries 
          MATCH (title,entry) AGAINST ('nice' WITH QUERY EXPANSION)
```

Comment: process in in PHP. It would be much easier

Comment: Why do you need to process words in mysql? Is there any reason for not doing this in PHP?

Comment: Actually after re-reading this about five times, it looks like OP doesn't want **anything** to do with PHP, and this is a MySQL only question? Really? This is concerned with a string search, and that's it....

Comment: I am afraid that it will have some performance penalties if i am using php. For example, in that case my current sql query will have to return whole value(text) from that cell and than i have to loop again results using php and search strings and finnaly display them in client side.
What i am trying to say is it would be much better if i get only portions of text from database and display them in client side, instead fetching all content from that cell and then process with php.

Comment: @user2269223 Why did you tag with [tag:php] and [tag:javascript] then?

Comment: I put PHP as tag, because this is a web project and all logic i do in PHP. I am looking for advice how to properly solve my problem because I do not know whether this is possible to accomplish with mysql,maybe i should solve this using PHP.

Comment: It's moving business logic to the data storage layer. It just makes no sense no matter what languages or platforms you are using, honestly use PHP :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### New Answer

OP is actually asking nothing to do with [php](/questions/tagged/php) and [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) - his question concerns doing string manipulation directly within MySQL.

String manipulation isn't really the main focus of a DBMS. When dealing with "words" in a fluid text sense, there's a lot of logic required to determine where the next word boundary is, and you don't want your database doing this really. Plus, any queries written to do this will probably be incredibly difficult to read.

It depends exactly what you are doing, but it's quite likely that a DB only approach will be slower because there will be more function calls: SQL functions are pretty limited.

And for *re-usability and best practice*, what if you wanted to change your database in the future to say MongoDB? You'd need to re-write the whole damned awkward query.

No, my suggestion would be to pull the whole value using standard MySQL into PHP, throw it into PCRE, very simple regex, job done. It's better to show what you're actually doing in your PHP code as it's more "intention revealing".

At least 33% of a developer's work is picking the right tool for the job. PHP is the right tool in this example.

### Original Answer

You have included the tags [php](/questions/tagged/php) and [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), so I'm guessing (although your question needs more clarification on this) that you *obviously* want this 'autocomplete' running client-side. So as a result, you have to **get your data from server-side to client-side** first.

Twitter Bootstrap has something really cool called [Typeahead](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html). This uses JavaScript to perform (what I think) you require: the example on that page shows how you can type a country and it'll auto-complete it for you. It looks like this:

[image]

How do you get this working? Include the required JavaScript file first, and then write your HTML.

Here's some from the source code of the bootstrap page so you can see how it works:

```
<input type="text" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4" data-source='["Alabama","Alaska","Arizona","Arkansas","California"]'>
```

Can you see how the `data-source` attribute is the one that gives the typeahead the information you want? You want to connect to MySQL, grab your data, and shove these into the `data-source` array for the JavaScript to work with, as above.

So, on your page load, you connect to MySQL and you pull all the relevant strings you would like to be "auto-complete-able" from the Database. You then put these as new Data attributes for the typeahead, and that's pretty much it!

--

Edit: There's a fork of twitter bootstrap's typeahead [that allows AJAX calls](https://gist.github.com/gudbergur/1866577), so you could use this to perform the data retrieval asynchronously (if you can figure it out, I'd recommend this approach).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i can not use typehead in my case. Problem is that i don't have predefined keywords and put them in js array, i must search database and return those results. Currently i am using ajax to display results with the query i wrote in question.
ps. sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: Okay problem is that you say you want "nice language" returned, or "nice features" returned. This makes sense, as we'll be searching for "nice" and then the next word. However, one of your examples shows "nice a language". How are you supposed to know when to end the search?

Comment: I'm just gonna throw out there that doing this in MySQL is merely cumbersome, **and probably slower** than doing it in PHP, because of the sheer number of function calls you're going to have to do in MySQL.

Comment: ok, so your advice is to use current query to fetch results and then process results  using php?
I prefer mysql because it has nice features for example full text boolean search.

Comment: Well for re-usability, readability, even speed, so in every important way really, PHP is a better fit for this. Use a simple query to fetch the value you want (you're already cutting down data costs by just getting specific fields instead of a `SELECT *`) - so grab the *whole value field*. Then use PHP to do your string manipulation. It'll be faster, easier to read / understand, and you'll have it done in no time. You don't want your DB using resources on every query when another process might need those resources for a more important query at a later date.

Comment: @user2269223 No worries. You should come back later and post a quick comment letting us know how it worked for you.

Comment: Sorry for late replay, yes it works very good, i fetch whole value and then process with php witch do the job very well.
Thank you again :)